# OfflineConversionError UNAUTHORIZED_USER

Tags: google-ads-api

I am working on a Google AdWords integration built on .NET, which was developed some time ago for API v201409. That version of the API has not been retired and I am now trying to migrate to the latest (v201506).
I have updated the Nuget package and it builds fine.

The account that I use to upload conversions is a manager account, with around 50 client accounts being managed by it.

When trying to upload conversions to some of the client accounts I am getting OfflineConversionError.UNAUTHORIZED_USER errors.

When I check the setup on the Google AdWords website everything looks fine. Each client account has the manager account set in the Account access settings.

I have used the ManagedCustomerService API to retrieve a list of client accounts that are managed by the manager account and it returns all accounts, including those that throw the error.

All refresh/access tokens appear to be working fine.

Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Comment: I have the same problem recently, but I'm still using v201502. The code is pretty new but worked for a few weeks without troubles.

Comment: @Jann I am in contact with Google account manager, so will hopefully have an answer from them soon

Comment: Great, I also took some more time to look into it, and the GCLIDs in question don't exist in my reports, so they either came from third parties or where not logged by Google (invalid clicks should appear in the report).

Comment: Any updates from Google?

Comment: They've asked me to capture the SOAP and send it to them and I haven't got round to it yet. I have successfully uploaded some conversions to the problem accounts today, so I'm guessing there is a problem with some of the data I'm trying to upload rather than a configuration issue.

Comment: Ah yes, it only happens with a few percent of the conversions with me. If you get anything useful back from Google, could you add it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OfflineConversionError.UNAUTHORIZED_USER is returned when you attempt to upload conversion data to an Adwords account other than the account that the click originated from.

If you have a manager account with multiple client accounts, make sure that the account ID is the correct one.